# Local IIS Web server cannot connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, iis

When I use the local IIS Web server, my ASP.NET MVC application is unable to connect to SQL Server. The database is on another server. However, if I use the Visual Studio Development Server, it works just fine.

Anyone know what settings I'm missing? Should something change in my Web.config?
Yes, TCP/IP is enabled on SQL Server.

Here is the error I get -

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a  connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible.  Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured  to allow remote connections. (provider:
>   Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could  not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)

Here is my connection string -

```
connectionString="
SERVER=servername;
Initial Catalog=dbname;
User ID=userid;
Password=passwd" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: Can you please **show us** the connection string you're using?

Comment: While you can make a named pipe connection to a different server, you really shouldn't do that. That's very likely to be related to your problem.

Comment: @marc_s, I added the connection string.

Comment: @IliaJerebtsov, what should I do differently? Thanks.

Comment: It'll depend on how you're addressing the server. Is your server actually called "servername"?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to sql server with visual studio, try to connect with visual studio to sql server (tools > connect to database > select Microsoft SQL server in dataSource box > press continue > and specify your access parameters to server), after establishing connection to sql server, open "server explorer" window > select your connection in data connection tree > open properties of connection and you will see "Connection String" property - it is your connection string, try to connect in your web app with it.

Comment: Your connstr look like ordinary TCP connection, and server is reporting named pipes error. Looks like client tried first TCP then NP and failed. Don't know why. However, try to drill a hole through your firewall, port 1433 and then reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use IP address to connect remote database something like SERVER=59.230.212.12 in connection string. Try to connect database in management studio from where your IIS is installed . then use same setting in connection string .